# Invalid parameter number error using DataTables with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, datatables

When DataTables tries to get data, it always gets tripped up on this Eloquent query:

```
$items = Item::select([
        DB::raw("images.url AS image"),
        'items.id',
        'items.sku',
        'items.quantity',
        DB::raw("IF(items.enabled, 'Yes', 'No') AS enabled")
    ])
        ->leftJoin('images', function ($j) {
            $j->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'items.id')
                ->where('images.imageable_type', '=', 'Item');
        })
        ->leftJoin('order_items', 'items.id', '=', 'order_items.item_id')
        ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
        ->where('items.store_id', 1)
        ->whereNull('items.deleted_at')
        ->whereIn('items.status', ['active', 'submitted'])
        ->groupBy('items.id');
```

The query works just fine as is and returns the desired results. However, DataTables tries to transform it into the following which produces the error:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as row from `items` left join `images` on `images`.`imageable_id` = `items`.`id` and `images`.`imageable_type` = 1 left join `order_items` on `items`.`id` = `order_items`.`item_id` left join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id` where `items`.`store_id` = 1 and `items`.`deleted_at` is null group by `items`.`id`) AS count_row_table
```

This produces this error specifically:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
/home/vagrant/Projects/test.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#301
```

When I execute that query directly on the MySQL database, it has no problem. This seems to be happening within Laravel only.

If I remove the `->leftJoin('images', function ($j) {...}` part of the query then there is no error, but I need that join for the image.

How to get around this error?

Full error output returned to DataTables over AJAX:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
      "message":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as row from `items` left join `images` on `images`.`imageable_id` = `items`.`id` and `images`.`imageable_type` = 1 left join `order_items` on `items`.`id` = `order_items`.`item_id` left join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id` where `items`.`store_id` = active and `items`.`deleted_at` is null and `items`.`status` in (submitted, ?) group by `items`.`id`) AS count_row_table)",
      "file":"\/home\/vagrant\/Projects\/test.dev\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php",
      "line":625
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact raw query being executed (without replacing any placeholders), and the bindings passed to the query?  If you have it available, the value of the `aQueries` key in the result from the `Datatables::of($items)->make();` statement would be great. Otherwise, I think you should be able to get this from the query log.

Comment: It never gets to `make()`. Bizarrely, when I look at the AJAX response returned to DataTables, I see `items.status in (submitted, ?)` which makes no sense, as the placeholder in that statement is a string literal `active` from the Eloquent `whereIn('items.status', ['active', 'submitted'])` portion of the query. Also, `items.store_id = active` is actually supposed to be `1` instead of `active`.

Comment: What do you get from a `dd(var_export($items->toSql(), true).PHP_EOL.var_export($items->getBindings(), true));` right after your `$items` assignment?  What version of the DataTables package are you using? Having you tried updating to the latest tagged release (I would not suggest using the master branch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact issue. The work around is not perfect since it will basically grab all the data twice, but it's the only way I could get it to work.

You have to do a `->get();` before sending it to `->make();`. I honestly hope someone finds the right solution but for now:

Temp solution:

```
$data = DB::table('some_table');

$data->leftJoin('some_other_table', function($join)
{
    $join->on('some_table.id', '=', 'some_other_table.id')
    ->where('some_table.something', '=', 'some_value');
});

$data->get();

return Datatables::of($data)->make();
```

This is with using the datatables package for Laravel: https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue today, not with DataTables but with a complex query being built using the standalone query builder. The issue was similar to yours with the left join, passing a closure to build a more complex join condition. I was using a where condition after the "on".

The solution was to chain "on" calls:

```
->leftJoin('images', function ($j) {
        $j->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'items.id')
            // note the "on" rather than the "where" and the use of a raw statement
            ->on('images.imageable_type', '=', DB::raw('Item'));
    })
```